# C# - Which members from the namespace are being used in the current file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Often, when I open a C# file in Visual Studio and I see the list of `using` statements at the top, I want to know exactly which members from those namespaces are being used in the current file. Is there a quick way to do that with Visual Studio?

For example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Class
{
    public IList<string> Method()
    {
        return new List<string>();
    }
}
```

This is a trivial class, and I can tell by inspection that we're using `IList` and `List` from the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace. For a longer class, could I have Visual Studio do this for me?

Let's assume that there are no unused `using`s.

Comment: comment out the using directives and check the compiler errors?

Comment: Another way to check is to look at the color.  In my copy of VS 2013, any unused using statements are usually light grey (I run the dark background color scheme).   Alternatively, you can right click on the file in the editor and select the menu option under Organize Usings (I think that's what's it called) and automatically remove the unused usings (and even organize by alphabetical order).

Comment: @Tim I thought the same thing but then I reread OP's post and I saw this *I want to know exactly which members from those namespaces are being used* so he wants to know what specifically is being used from those namespaces

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid - Ah, good catch.  I didn't see that on first read.

Comment: @RenéVogt I'd accept that as an answer if that's the only way, but I was hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: @FrankTan - There might be some third party tools that could do that for you (maybe ReSharper?)

Comment: There are tools like R# (resharper) that do this for you. That happens to be a paid tool but there are probably free extensions or tools as well that could do this.

Comment: I don't know if it's the _only_ way but @ReneVogts answer is exactly what I would do

Comment: Is there any reason you want to know this or why it is important to you? Having extra/unused `using` statements does not do anything to the runtime speed of the generated code and they are completely ignored at compile time. Unless you have stacks of using statements across thousands of code files it would not affect the compile time speed either (that you would notice).

Comment: @Igor To make it a little easier to understand an unfamiliar class. I see that class A is using something from namespace B, and I'd like to know why.